# Chaning the select option value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select html form element with a range of option values as per below.

```
<select name="budget" id="budget" class="selectInput required">
<option value="" selected>Select an option...</option>
<option value="£5-£10K">£5-£10K</option>
<option value="£5-£10K">£10-£15K</option>
</select>
```

I would like to be able to change the value of these options in jQuery - how can I do this??? I thought this would work - but it doesnt seem too?

```
$("#budget option[value='£5-£10K']").val('Monkeys');
```

e.g. changing the value of the option that had '£5-£10k' to become 'Monkeys'

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It works, inspect your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `option` element has two key properties - `value` and `text`. You're changing one but not the other:

```
$("#budget option[value='£5-£10K']").val('Monkeys').text('Monkeys');
```

In no circumstance will setting the `value` change the `text`, however if your `option` element does not have a `value` attribute, the `value` is set to the `text`.

Comment: As the accepted answer it might be worth clarifying that without a value the text of the `<option>` is used/submitted as the value (so it might be easier in this instance to simply omit the use of the `value` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

**Another way in jQuery below**

```
$("#budget>option[value='£5-£10K']").text('Monkeys or something else').val('Monkeys or whatever');
```